# print content of a tag

Tags: regex

I have an HTML content which I was asked to extract the content of the tags using regex. I know they must be an elegant way to do that using beautiful soup but I was asked to do that using regex. 
I have html content

```html
<div id="sym">
<div id="Y" class="s"><a class="ey" href="/browse/o">orange</a></div>
<div id="Y" class="s"><a class="ey" href="/browse/m">mango</a></div>
<div id="Y" class="s"><a class="ey" href="/browse/b">banana</a></div>
<div id="Y" class="s"><a class="ey" href="/browse/a">apple</a></div>
</div>
```

I want to print out

```html
orange
mango
banana
apple
```

i've try, but the output is empty.

```html
import re
file = open('test.html')
myfile = file.read()
lines = myfile.splitlines()
matching=re.findall(r'<div[^>]*class=.*?s[^>]*>',myfile)
for style in matching:
    for b in style:
        c=re.findall(r'<a[^>]*class=.*?ey>([^<]+)</a>',b)
        print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this pattern would do:

```
<.*>(\w+)<.*>
```

and then you capture the first group of this regex.

link for regex101:
https://regex101.com/r/QFHS8g/1